# Android Studio 3.0 annotationProcessor

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I get the following error after I try to build my project:

```
Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.
```

I tried to add `annotationProcessor '.....'` after every `implementation` but no success to get rid of the error.

This happens after upgrading android studio to the latest version ( 3.0 ).

Edit:

Adding `includeCompileClasspath true` inside `defaultConfig` doesn't help:

```
    javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath true
        }
    }
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, It happened because of realm, I updated the realm library to the latest version because some old version was using adt-plugin.

Comment: @MarianPavel Please specify the latest version of realm which solves your problem

Comment: @EmptyData the latest stable version is 4.3.4 while there is a latest beta version 5.0.0-BETA1

Answer (score 32):

First of all, after upgrading there are a few changes to gradle.

Its important to upgrade to the latest gradle version to fix that.

That means that you need to add the proper version for your build gradle which is currently

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
 }
```

the next step is to remove your  `android-apt` which is not longer needed.

its enough to have only `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Onec you have done that, change your dependencies from

`compile` to `implementation`, `apt` to `annotationProcessor` and `testCompile` to `androidTestImplementation`

If you have done that invalidate your cache and restart which is very important.

Then it should work.

You can find a working gradle file using the latest version at

[app build.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/build.gradle) and [project build.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/build.gradle)

p/s : For many people still use Realm old version,

Please update to latest version since old version still use "android-apt".

Answer (score 2):

you have to add `annotationProcessorOptions` in app level gradle.

```
android {    
compileSdkVersion 26    
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'    
defaultConfig { 
   applicationId "com.your.packagename"  
   minSdkVersion 16
   targetSdkVersion 26
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" 

   // add below section
   javaCompileOptions {
        annotationProcessorOptions {
            includeCompileClasspath true
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mentions that I tried this. Any other solutions?

Comment: This option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
  See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.

Comment: does not work..